# File System Object VB

Tags: vba

```
Sub Command3_Click()
      Dim fs As FileSystemObject
      Dim f As TextStream
      Dim a As Variant
      Dim i As Long

      Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

      ' Read file into array
       If fs.FileExists("C:\rbc.csv") Then
           Set f = fs.OpenTextFile("C:\rbc.csv", ForReading, False)
           a = Split(f.ReadAll, vbNewLine, -1, vbTextCompare)
           f.Close
       Else
           MsgBox "The file path is invalid.", vbCritical, vbNullString
           Exit Sub
       End If
      ' Write line > 1 to file
      Set f = fs.OpenTextFile("C:\rbc.csv", ForWriting, True)
      For i = 1 To UBound(a)
        f.WriteLine a(i)
      Next
      f.Close
End Sub
```

It worked fine when I tried it on csv files , but then I  had a problem . One of the files has the first line as "   A,B,C,D,  " (NO Quotes ) and second file has first line as
`"  01-JUL-2014,RBC_BASELII_07012014,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, "` .

Now when I try to delete the first line of the second file , the entire file text gets deleted , while it deletes only one line at a time in the first file. Please help me out.

Comment: My guess is that the second file doesn't have carriage returns so the whole file is one big line (if you consider vbNewLine the divider). Write another procedure that opens the second file and finds the first chr(10) and see if the next character is chr(13). If it's not, you have to split on chr(10) rather than vbNewLine (which is both chr(10) and chr(13). But that will cause a little problem for any files that do use both, so you have to handle it.

Comment: But I figured out that if I open the file and press ctrl + s and close it and then if I try the program works . So what can be the problem ?

Comment: Whatever program you're opening the file in is converting the line breaks into Chr10Chr13 line breaks. If I create a file with vbCr line breaks and open it in Notepad, everything is on the same line. If I open it in Wordpad, save it (without changing anything), then reopen it in Notepad, it's on two lines. Wordpad, for one example, will replace any carriage return with Chr10Chr13. Are these files coming from a linux system?

Comment: No they are from windows . So I think you just got the solution . Let me know what should I do . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the comments explain what's going on.

```
Sub Command3_Click()
    Dim fs As FileSystemObject
    Dim f As TextStream
    Dim a As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sLineBreak As String
    Dim sAll As String

    Const sFILE As String = "K:\rbc.csv"

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If fs.FileExists(sFILE) Then
        Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(sFILE, ForReading, False)
        sAll = f.ReadAll
        'if there are cr's, then it's either only cr's or it's both
        If InStr(1, sAll, vbCr) > 0 Then
            a = Split(sAll, vbCr, -1, vbTextCompare)
        Else 'no cr's means it's only line feeds
            a = Split(sAll, vbLf, -1, vbTextCompare)
        End If

        f.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "The file path is invalid.", vbCritical, vbNullString
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Write line > 1 to file
    Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(sFILE, ForWriting, True)
    For i = 1 To UBound(a)
        'if there are cr's, then we split on them, so they wouldn't
        'be there anymore. But if it was both, there would be
        'vblf's left over and we want to get rid of those
        f.WriteLine Replace(a(i), vbLf, vbNullString)
    Next
    f.Close
End Sub
```